# Is it possible to load a save file from a game of another region (PS3)?

Tags: ps3, batman-arkham-asylum

I played Batman: Arkham Asylum (BLES) for a while and got almost all the available trophies (the PS3 equivalent of achievements). Yesterday I bought the Collector's Edition (BLUS) and I noticed that I could not use the same save file I used before.

I don't wanna to play the game from beginning right now, I just want to get every trophy and be ready to play Batman: Arkham City.

**Does anyone know if I can do something to fix that?**

P.S. BLES - European Game; BLUS - US Game

Comment: i tried it with cross edge without succes, btw is  the colectors edition dlc or retail? (dlc are region coded but games arent)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, you're up the creek. Save game files are locked to the region of the disk (at least in the cases I've dealt with). You could try logging a support request with the developer to see if they can help you out.

Some game saves are locked to region, others to the PSN account name, and I'

Comment: I'? Did something happen?! Are you alright Mel? Mel?? MEEEEEEEL!!!!!!

Comment: @Mana don't worry, he just started a new journey thats al...

Comment: Weird, not sure wh